# Base64 to decimal in Nodejs or javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, decimal

I've generated a private RSA key which is encoded in Base64. I want to get some parameters like public exponent, modulus... in decimal to operate with them.

I've tried to decode the key with buffers but I get strange symbols like these

```
var b = new Buffer(pubKey, 'base64')
var s = b.toString();
```

s output:

```
ڴkg}v�(MR^y�*]��}ODӂ>���Ve�mL���OAڣ������Yʁ�{�7     �w����Z�������-=�hz��_�e2ժ�Y�LkW
```

How can I take a base64 string and convert it to decimal numbers?

Thank you!!

Comment: I could be totally wrong here, but did you try just `atob` and `btoa` ?

Comment: JS can only represent integers precisely up to 2^53. You won't be able to convert an RSA private key to a single integer value in JS.

Comment: Even using some bignumber library? Then I can't operate with decimal RSA keys in JS?

Comment: A big number library will of course be able to deal with such values. My point was that you can't convert such as string to a JS number value. A big number library will use a different representation for such values.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with RSA keys, there are modules on npm that might help you, for example: [`node-forge`](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge), [`jsencrypt`](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt), and [`node-rsa`](https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa). These modules should allow you to get at the individual components of the RSA keys.

Comment: Honestly in NodeJS I wouldn't use jsencrypt. It has been developed keeping well in mind that it WILL run in the browser and it will perform poorly in a nodejs environment (moreover you will have to simulate some browsers' variables). In nodejs you can have access to openssl and it would be way better to do so instead of relying on JSEncrypt. I'm really proud of the work I did on it but still I will not advise to use it in other environments than the browsers ones.